# How Load Store Architecture differentiatiate between alu operations and memory access instruction

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv

I am going through RiscV architecture. I came to know that like other RISC architecture it is also a load store architecture. I searched on google and learnt about load store architecture and it tells that in load store architecture for performing an operations for example addition operation, both the operands must be loaded to registers from memory and then operation is performed and result is again stored in the memory from registers. The next statement that is it can differentiate between instruction between ALU operations and memory access.
Can anyone tell how it does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> both the operands must be loaded to registers from memory and then operation is performed and result is again stored in the memory from registers.

This a bit misleading or oversimplified.

First, this only happens if the operands are all in memory such as in the following expression: 
    `a[i] = b[i] + c[i];`
where you would have two loads and one store.

By contrast an expression like `i = i + 1;` would usually have `i` in a register already, so that would just be one instruction — no loads or stores.

Second, non-load/store architectures might be able to express a memory addition with fewer instructions, but they still have to do the same kind of work: fetch operands from memory, add within the CPU, and store result back to memory.

> The next statement that is it can differentiate between instruction between ALU operations and memory access.

The simple answer is that the loads and stores and ALU operations all have different opcodes.  The opcode tells the CPU (and software disassemblers and humans) the instruction format, and the format may also have a secondary opcode that further differentiates operations.  (On RISC V, the first two bits of the opcode informs on the instruction size as to whether 32 bits or 16 bits, while more bits are used for 48 bit and larger instructions.)

The approach of looking at opcode fields and possibly secondary opcode fields is not unique to load/store architectures — all instruction set architectures use opcode fields, for example to understand the length of an instruction (if needed by that implementation) and the number, meaning, and position/sizes of its operands.  See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture#Instruction_encoding

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir @Erik Eidt. Sir then if non load/store architectures also works in same way as load/store architectures, then what is the fundamental difference between them?

Comment: In some sense, all computers have a CPU interconnected via a bus to Memory, so no fundamental difference there.  However, a load/store architecture offers [addressing modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) for memory access only in the load & store instructions, whereas other architectures support addressing modes in all instruction types; tradeoffs include easier to express certain things in one instruction but more complex decode, more difficult to reuse memory operands as these are not saved within the CPU.